# Remove old API data in database no web hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, api

new to ruby and ruby on rails here.

Have database which gets all articles from API and saves it. This works by find or create, however this way it never deletes articles. It only gets the current articles and new articles, but no webhook to tell me if an article is removed. How can I do this without a web hook to tell me if an article has been removed? Purging database every day is not an option because of other data linked.

I can't seem to find anything without the use of webhooks. Any one ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no Webhook to tell you the article removed-status. You only have two ways to remove the old-article.

1. Use polling to query the API to check the article removed-status. If the article has removed been checked by your polling, you can remove the old-article.
2. Set a time-base, for example : seven days, then if the article created in your database over seven days, you seem the article to a old-article, and you remove the old-article.

The disadvantage of 1.way make more system cost.
The disadvantage of 2.way is inaccurate.

All the ways aren't perfect, but if you have no Webhook, this is only two ways that you can do.